# SQL query align sequence of events in one row

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Hope you all enjoying holidays and fun time. Reply to this when you get a chance.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

The issues is - there is a process in one of our teams which do things in sequence of events/actions. Mostly it is 4 actions/events for every sequence. These events are fixed. When they perform this DWH gets an entry for each event as a separate row.

Example
1) Call Customer
2) Sell Insurance
3) Send PDS
4) Send details to product team

I've it set in a way that all Actions and their definitions are in Dimension_Point_Code table. All events that come through from DWH are treated as Fact and stored in Fact_Point

The Point here refers to the Point in the sequence of the process.

So the table that store this info looks like below

Dimension table

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_Dim_Point_Code]
(
[Point_Code_Key] [int] IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL,
[Point_Code] [varchar](8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Point_Code_TouchPoint] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Fact Table

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_FACT_Point]
(
[Point_Key] [bigint] IDENTITY(100,1) NOT NULL,
[Point_Code_Key] [int] NOT NULL,
[Customer_Number] [varchar](19) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Sale_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Rep_ID] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data in Dimension

```
INSERT INTO [tbl_Dim_Point_Code]
       ([Point_Code]
       ,[Point_Code_TouchPoint])

Select 'CALC' as Point_Code,'Point1' as Point_Code_TouchPoint
UNION
Select 'SELL' as Point_Code,'Point2' as Point_Code_TouchPoint
UNION
Select 'SPDS' as Point_Code,'Point3' as Point_Code_TouchPoint
UNION
Select 'TPRD' as Point_Code,'Point4' as Point_Code_TouchPoint
```

Data in Fact

```
INSERT INTO [tbl_FACT_Point]
       ([Point_Code_Key]
       ,[Customer_Number]
       ,[Sale_Date]
       ,[Rep_ID])
Select 101,'C101501','24-Feb-2012','ABC'
UNION
Select 102,'C101501','24-Feb-2012','ABC'
UNION
Select 103,'C101501','26-Feb-2012','DEF'
UNION
Select 104,'C101501','27-Feb-2012','XYZ'
UNION
Select 101,'C101502','2-Feb-2012','GHI'
UNION
Select 102,'C101502','2-Feb-2012','GHI'
UNION
Select 104,'C101502','4-Feb-2012','XYZ'
UNION
Select 101,'C101503','14-Feb-2012','ABC'
UNION
Select 103,'C101503','20-Feb-2012','ABC'
UNION
Select 104,'C101503','22-Feb-2012','BBC'
UNION
Select 101,'C101501','24-Oct-2012','ABC'
UNION
Select 102,'C101501','24-Oct-2012','ABC'
UNION
Select 103,'C101501','26-Oct-2012','DEF'
UNION
Select 104,'C101501','27-Oct-2012','XYZ'
```

Points to note
1) As you can see Customer C101501 was called & sold the twice.
2) And the processing for the all involved happends everyday - like the team, the DWH and the SQL Server Process. Hence most of the times we will not know what is going to happen. We will only know that Event 1 has occured. then few days later event 2 and so on.
3) 101 & 104 are mandatory events. 102 and 103 may or may not occur. The team will contact Product team irrespective of sale or not.

Now - what we want is that the entries to be transposed into this table

```
CREATE TABLE [tbl_Process1_EVENT]
(
[HS_EVENT_KEY] [int] IDENTITY(101,1) NOT NULL,
[Customer_Number] [varchar](19) ,
[Import_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Point1_Date_Called] [datetime] NULL,
[Point1_PointCode] [varchar](8) ,
[Point1_Rep_Id] [varchar](50) ,
[Point2_Date_Sold] [datetime] NULL,
[Point2_PointCode] [varchar](8) ,
[Point2_Rep_Id] [varchar](50) ,
[Point3_Date_PDSSent] [datetime] NULL,
[Point3_PointCode] [varchar](8) ,
[Point3_Rep_Id] [varchar](50) ,
[Point4_Date_ProdTeamXfer] [datetime] NULL,
[Point4_PointCode] [varchar](8) ,
[Point4_Rep_Id] [varchar](50) 
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

What I'd want to happen is, an output like this.

```
Customer_Number Import_Date Point1_Date_Called  Point1_PointCode    Point1_Rep_Id   Point2_Date_Sold    Point2_PointCode    Point2_Rep_Id   Point3_Date_PDSSent Point3_PointCode    Point3_Rep_Id   Point4_Date_ProdTeamXfer    Point4_PointCode    Point4_Rep_Id
C101501         28/02/2012  24/02/2012          CALC                ABC             24/02/2012          SELL                ABC             26/02/2012          SPDS                DEF             27/02/2012                  TPRD                XYZ
C101502         3/02/2012   2/02/2012           CALC                GHI             2/02/2012           SELL                GHI             NULL                NULL                NULL            4/02/2012                   TPRD                ABC
C101503         23/02/2012  14/02/2012          CALC                ABC             NULL                NULL                NULL            20/02/2012          SPDS                ABC             22/02/2012                  TPRD                BBC
C101501         28/10/2012  24/10/2012          CALC                ABC             24/10/2012          SELL                ABC             26/10/2012          SPDS                DEF             27/10/2012                  TPRD                XYZ
```

Transposing the data into rows with new entry for C101501 if new sale is made on same customer.
Import_date is the date when the Row is Updated.
As i said processing happens everyday.

So if I can elaborate this table for line 1 of this output

On 24/02/2012 the Event CALC occurs - we know about this on 25/02/2012 Point 1 & Point 2 on 25/02 will be filled with data and Point 3 & Point 4 will be empty. Import_Date - will be 25/02/2012

On 26/02/2012 PDS is sent which is point 3. So the same row will be updated. Point 3 only will be updated. Import_date will be 27/02/2012

On 27/02/2012 Point 4 event occurs. Hence on 28/02/2012 the same row will be updated with Point 4 details.

That's all I can think about the issue.

Please any help any time will be greatly appreciated.

Njoy holidays and have a good time.

PS: I may have done something wrrong with the format of output. Please advise I can make it better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the pivot command (aka cross tab). Its not easy to get your head around:

the following links should / could help:

http://geekswithblogs.net/lorint/archive/2006/08/04/87166.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1019/crosstab-queries-using-pivot-in-sql-server/

http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/

good lucj

Comment: I am not sure if pivoting is an option. I tried but i may be missing some logic. I'll try and give it some more time tonight. Thanks